# ListSelect - getting no optionInfo key on second click in list

Tags: list, actions-on-google

I am using a webhook for my Google Action that shows a ListSelect to the user. If the user clicks the first time on an item, my webhook receives the respective optionInfo key. Everything works as expected. But if the user scrolls up and clicks on another item in that list, I only receive the title of item as text and not the connected optionInfo key as attribute.

After the user has clicked on an item the first time, my Google Action sends a SimpleResponse with some text, so that there is no more the 'action.intent.OPTION' intent given as possibleIntent then. In each response the "actions.intent.TEXT" intent is included in the "possibleIntents" field.

So my question is, is there any way to get the optionInfo key of the selected item from the list anytime the user selects an item?

My list looks like this:

```
"possibleIntents": [
    {
        "intent": "actions.intent.OPTION",
        "inputValueData": {
            "listSelect": {
                "title": "Select an item",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "optionInfo": {
                            "key": "item_1"
                        },
                        "title": "Item #1",
                        "description": "Description 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "optionInfo": {
                            "key": "item_2"
                        },
                        "title": "Item #2",
                        "description": "Description 2"
                     },
                     {
                        "optionInfo": {
                            "key": "item_3"
                        },
                        "title": "Item #3",
                        "description": "Description 3"
                      }
                ]
            },
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.OptionValueSpec"
       }
   },
   {
       "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
   }
]
```

After the user selects an item my webhooks sends these possible intents:

```
"possibleIntents": [
   {
       "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
   }
]
```

If the user now scrolls up and selects another item from the list I don't receive the optionInfo key.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question you asked but I think the answer is no. Further, your action has to be in a position to accept text because the user can choose to speak rather than tap. FWIW, what I do, is to save the text and the keys in my 'session' object as I build the list. Then no matter how the user replies I am covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google fixed it by hiding the other items in that list after a click on one item was made.